# How to hide a Google maps circle objects after different time intervals?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Lets say i have 2 cricle objects on my google map.
I want to remove each circle from the map after 3 seconds after creation.

This is the code. The problem is that the setTimeout works only for the last circle which i create..
How can i make it work?

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(centerLan, centerLon),
        zoom: 10
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function setAlarm(lon, lat) {
    var alarmPosition = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lon, lat),
        radius: Math.sqrt(150) * 100
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(alarmPosition);

    //trying to remove the circle after some time

        setTimeout(function() {
    cityCircle.setMap(null);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `setAlarm`? And I'm guessing you call it three times?

Comment: @putvande I read cordinations from a json file and then sent the cords to the setAlarm() function to create a circle. The number of circles is dynamic. but for the example i used only 2. So, the unmber of circles = the number of calls to setAlarm().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the variable local:

```
//note the var-keyword  
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(alarmPosition);
```

Otherwise it will be overwritten on each call of `setAlarm` and you may only remove the circle that has been created in the last call.

Comment: OMG i cant believe i did that mistake. Thank you very much!